# Form validation with array with forbidden form values in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am working on a simple Angular form that has two validator rules:

1. The value must not be empty
2. The value cannot be one of the previously defined values (from array `forbiddenValues`).

I know that I can easily add the required validator as follows:

```
this.titleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'title': ['', Validators.required]
});
```

How can I however dynamically also add a rule for my array `forbiddenValues`?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

Comment: That doesn't show how you can dynamically add an array, only a hardcoded example is given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a some-kind-of-a factory for validation (actually just a lambda):

```
this.titleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   'title': ['', [Validators.required, (control: AbstractControl) => {
       return this.forbiddenValues.indexOf(control.value) === -1 ? null : {'forbiddenValue': true};
    }]
});
```

But you need to manually trigger form validation every time the forbidden values change, using `this.titleForm.updateValueAndValidity()`

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to centralize the validation function for you use in more than one place, this is something that could work for you.

```
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, AbstractControl, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

function isForbidden(forbiddenValues: string[]): ValidatorFn {
  return (c: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: boolean } | null => {
    if (forbiddenValues.indexOf(c.value) !== -1) {
      return { 'forbiddenValues': true };
    }
    return null;
  };
}

@Component({...

this.titleForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'title': ['', [Validators.required, isForbidden(this.forbiddenValues)]]
});
```